# Swift scaleAspectFit only height of image

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this imageview in my Swift code

```
let background_image: UIImageView = {
    let im = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backg")
    let view=UIImageView()
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.image=im
    return view
}()
```

My `background_image`'s size is 300x300,but i don't know the size of `im`.I want width of `im` always be 300,but i don't want to shrink the height,i just want to show the 300px that fit in UIImageView

Comment: That's what `scaleAspectFill` will do assuming the height is larger than the width.

Comment: @dan `scaleAspectFill ` show last 300px,how can i make it show first 300px?

Comment: Sounds like you want `scaleAspectFit` instead of `scaleAspectFill`. Could you add a visual example to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the aspect ratio, and use the know width of 300, also you need to setup your `UIImageView` content mode to `aspectFit`

This code example uses `SDWebImage` for image loading, but you can use any other

```
self.newsImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "genericImageR"), options: SDWebImageOptions(), completed: { (image, error, type, url) in
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if(image != nil)
                    {
                        //your downloaded image aspect ratio
                        let aspectRatio = (image! as UIImage).size.height/(image! as UIImage).size.width
                        self.newsImageView.image = image
                        if(self.imageWasLoaded != nil)
                        {
                            //your know width 300, but if you want you can use the width of your component
                            self.imageWasLoaded!(self.newsImageView.frame.size.width * aspectRatio)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

and adjust your UI with the heigth result of 300*aspectRatio

I hope this helps you